# how to draw a negative exponential plot of this situation with python

Tags: python, dataset, matplotlib

I have a dataset with binary output ($Y$) and I have a column (Duration) contains the duration of each task that is stored by "days" and varied from 1day to 350 days.

when I think logically in our situation, I can deduce that the probability of getting a positive output value ($Y = 1$) require to have small duration task.

But I need to justify my opinion with some plots

I have tried the following source code but It doesn't represent correctly my assumption.

```
#LoadData

min_duration = plot_data['Duration'].min()
max_duration = plot_data['Duration'].max()
xr_ = list(range(min_duration,  max_duration,  5))
y_ = []

for i in range(0,(len(xr_)-1)):
    a_ = np.logical_and(plot_data['Duration'].values >= xr_[i], plot_data['Duration'].values < xr_[i+1])
    b_ = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(plot_data['Duration'].values >= xr_[i], plot_data['Duration'].values < xr_[i+1]), plot_data['output'].values==1)
    y_.append(sum(b_)/sum(a_))

import matplotlib
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(xr_[1:len(xr_)], y_, 'o')
```

Based on my previous assumption I must get a plot which contains an exponential form like :

[image]

But I have got contrary the following plot:

[image]

I want to know where I have a mistake and If there is any other method to justify my assumption

Answer (score 1):

The model you are looking for is this:

$Y=A e^{-Bx} + c$, I know the implementation in R, because I don't know of a nonlinear estimation in Python

This code in R might work:

```
R=data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),Y=c(1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)) # Data in which X, Y are your data
model=nls(formula = Y~A*exp(-B*X)+C,data=R)
summary(model)
```

There is a limitation to take into account, is explained in this link, is summarized in the impossibility for all possible models to exist, the "most inside" model should be linear.

[First steps with Non-Linear Regression in R](https://datascienceplus.com/first-steps-with-non-linear-regression-in-r/)

[Singular Gradient Error in nls with correct starting values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13053/singular-gradient-error-in-nls-with-correct-starting-values)

Comment: Thank you juan, I will try to look for the equivalent function in python .

Comment: @Nirmine Check out [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for Python.